I found a strange problem when using il2cpp to package a mobile platform in Unity
In my scene, there are some 2D objects named BlockRoot, and the layer is Block. As a parent, it only adds a component BoxCollider2D. It has a child with SpriteRenderer to render images. I have a function to click on this object BlockRoot and get its script. This is the key code：
public void UpdateState(TetrisStateMachine stateMachine)
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Block");
            Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            Collider2D hitCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePosition, layerMask);

            Log.Info("Touch Start "+ mousePosition + " , "+ layerMask);

            if (hitCollider != null)
            {
                Log.Info("Touch hitCollider "+ hitCollider.name);
                Block block = hitCollider.GetComponent<Block>();
                if (block != null)
                {
                    block.DeleteByPlayer();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("Touch no Block");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("Touch no hitCollider");
            }
        }
    }
}

In the unity editor and the apk packaged with mono, I can click on this object on the screen, and the code runs normally. It can execute to the code “block.DeleteByPlayer()”
However, when I use il2cpp to package the apk, I find that I can't get the script of block，then log is "Touch no hitCollider".
so I add another 2d Square to the scene, add BoxCollider2D to it, and set the layer to Block to test whether it can be clicked. When I use il2cpp to package the apk, I find that the previous BlockRoot and the newly added 2d Square can both be clicked
Then I delete the newly added 2d Square from the scene, and then use il2cpp to package the apk, and find that the previous BlockRoot cannot be clicked again.log is "Touch no hitCollider".
So does anyone know what the reason is? It has been bothering me for two days. It's so interesting.

What is Camera? Have you debugged the bounds of the BoxCollider2D when tapping?

hi，camrea is scene main camera , yes , touch pos is right in BoxCollider2D
